# What is the correct way to insert data into a Cassandra UDT?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

Here is the type I have created,

```
CREATE TYPE urs.dest (
destinations frozen<list<text>>);
```

And here is the table ,

```
CREATE TABLE urs.abc (
id int,
locations map<text, frozen<dest>>,
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

When I try to insert values from cqlsh,

try 1:

```
insert into urs.abc (id, locations ) values (1, {'coffee': { 'abcd', 'efgh'}});
```

try 2:

```
insert into urs.abc (id, locations ) values (1, {'coffee': ['abcd', 'efgh']});
```

try 3:

```
insert into urs.abc (id) values (1);
update urs.abc set locations = locations + {'coffee': {'abcd','qwer'}} where id=1;
```

I'm getting the below error,

```
Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid map literal for locations: value {'abcd', 'qwer'} is not of type frozen<dest>"
```

Can anyone please let me know the correct way to add value to my UDT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table creation seems fine

To insert to the table to `urs.abc` use this

```
insert into urs.abc (id, locations ) values (1, {'coffee':{ destinations: ['abcd', 'efgh']}});
```

You are missing the field name `destinations`.